# Reduced graphs and pinch-singular surfaces

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, quantum-chromodynamics, feynman-diagrams

I am reading a [book](http://www.cambridge.org/us/academic/subjects/physics/particle-physics-and-nuclear-physics/foundations-perturbative-qcd) on perturbative QCD by John Collins. In Chapter 5, the terms ***reduced graph*** and ***pinch-singular surface*** are used for the analysis of mass singularities. However, their meanings are not explainded very clearly. It says (Sect 5.1.4, page 91)

> The PSSs (for the physical region, which is all that concerns us) are where
>   the on-shell propagators and momenta correspond to classically allowed
>   scattering processes treated in coordinate space.

I cannot get the key points from this *definition*. For reduced graphs, it provides some examples. But I still cannot understand why they are important and how they are related to the Feynman diagrams. Could someone help me to clarify these terminologies? Many thanks!

Comment: Maybe this [paper](http://www.hep.man.ac.uk/u/forshaw/Tim-Thesis.pdf) - Chapter 2.2 pages 18 to 22, Figure 2.1 and Figure 2.2 page 23 - might interest you.

Comment: https://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-ph/0412013.pdf is a discussion by Sterman.  Pg 20 explains the two concepts.